# I need to know how can I display products in a page like (cart, below total)

Tags: cart

I need to know how can I display products in a page like (cart, below total) only few products by ID. Eg: products with id 2,3,4 and 5.

Comment: can you be more eloborate?

Answer (score 1):

Steps to show selected product on the cart page below the totals: 
1. Create a dummy category in admin and assign the products.
2. Disable that category as you don't need to show anywhere.
3. Call that category products using below code on /var/www/html/magento8/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml file.

```
<?php
    $categoryid = 4;(here you can put the category id that you had created in admin)
    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); ?>
    <ul>
<?php
    foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

4. Make the css changes as per needs.